Get dynamic form inputs as JSON
I have an HTML form with many inputs. After submitting the form I should get these values as JSON format. The challenge here is that the form has dynamic fields that can be increased/decreased during form filling "items". I'm trying to handle these inputs, but I couldn't reach the desired result which is to put each of group of the dynamic fields inside an array (nested JSON).
I am posting this JSON using AJAX but if there is PHP approach to achieve this, that is OK too.
This is the output that I get:
{
"id": "101",
"name": "MY LLC", 
"project": "Project A",
"date": "12/10/2023",  
"items": [{"items_0xdescription": "description of first item", "items_1xquantity": "1", "items_2xrate": "200", "items_3xamount": "1","items_4xdescription": "description of second item", "items_5xquantity": "1", "items_6xrate": "100", "items_7xamount": "1"}], 
"terms": "terms for this doc", 
"notes": "notes for this doc"
}

The items_Nx I created it so that I have unique names for each input because it keeps overwriting on previous records.
I was thinking of handling it later using /.split("x").pop()/
This is the desired result:
{
"id": "101",
"name": "MY LLC", 
"project": "Project A",
"date": "12/10/2023",  
"items": [{"description": "description of first item", "quantity": "1", "rate": "200", "amount": "1"}, 
            {"description": "description of second item", "quantity": "1", "rate": "100", "amount": "1"}], 
"terms": "terms for this doc", 
"notes": "notes for this doc"
}

The dynamic form inputs:
<?php foreach($i->items as $item) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="col-md-6">
            <div >
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $item->description; ?>" name="<?php echo 'items_'.$itms++.'xdescription'; ?>">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1">
            <div >
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $item->quantity; ?>" name="<?php echo 'items_'.$itms++.'xquantity'; ?>">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1">
            <div >
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $item->rate; ?>" name="<?php echo 'items_'.$itms++.'xrate'; ?>">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="text-end col-md-1">
            <div class="">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo "$". $item->amount ?>" name="<?php echo 'items_'.$itms++.'xamount'; ?>">
            </div>
                
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

This is static part of the input
<div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
   <input class="form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $i->project; ?>" name="project">
</div>

This is the JS code that I use:
function convertFormToJSON() {

    var data = $('#editForm');
    const array = $(data).serializeArray();
    const json = {};
    const tempItems = {};

        $.each(array, function () {
            if (this.name.includes('items')){
                tempItems[this.name] = this.value || "";
            }else{
                json[this.name] = this.value || "";
            }
        });

    json['items'] = tempItems;
    console.log(json);
}


Perhaps you need to show what the form looks like - the items_nx... looks odd for a start and your code doesn't seem to do anything to remove it

Questions here cannot depend on screenshots of text. Please add your output/desired result as text.

why do the values you get include $ for the amount, and your desired values do not? Why is the amount for "second item" $200 in what you get, but 100 in what you desire?

It's a shame the question was closed just as I was posting an answer

I have updated the question as you mentioned and submitted for review.
